# Set bash_profile to open with Sublime Text 2 by default

Tags: terminal, bash, sublimetext

I'd like Sublime Text 2, not TextEdit, to be the default program to open my `bash_profile` file when I call `open ~/.bash_profile` in Terminal. Normally I would just control-click on the file in Finder to set the default program, but given that `bash_profile` is hidden I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Have you tried unhiding it? Also, though I'm not sure if this would work, you could create your own foobar.bash_profile file and set the default program like you stated above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can temporarily show hidden files. In terminal write:

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`

and then `killall Finder` to restart Finder.

Change what you need and then hide hidden files again by changing `TRUE` to `FALSE`.

Edit: Making this more explicit. In Finder, locate .bash_profile, open up the properties by right click + "Get Info". Then change the "Open with" to Sublime Text 2. This works, I just tried it.

[image]

Comment: @Mark I think you misunderstood. I updated the instructions. This method sets the default so that it does not open in TextEdit.

Comment: this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
subl .bash_profile
```

instead of `open`. You can launch Sublime Text with `subl`, and append a filename to open it.

Comment: this doesn't answer the OP

Answer (score 2):

You can do `open -a "Sublime Text 2" ~/.profile` Assuming that name is what's on the app's bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time, but i do it from the command line:

My bash profile has the st macro mapped to:

`alias st='/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'`

And in the terminal i just type:

`st ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1):

## Sublime Text Shortcut Guide

1. Open Mac Terminal
2. Go to [homebrew.sh](http://brew.sh); copy and enter the following:
   `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
3. Enter `brew install wget`
4. Enter the following into your Mac Terminal: `open ~/.bash_profile` but if for whatever reason you don't have one configured, enter
   `sudo nano .bash_profile`.  **Please be advised, this solution presumes you are the root user of your system/device.**
5. Open another tab within the terminal-window and check Ruby version (e.g. `ruby -v`); if absent, become sufficiently by Rubified by entering: `brew install ruby`
6. Download Sublime Text 3, then go to root/usr (e.g. `cd alexanderjsingleton/`).
7. Next after you've installed Sublime 3, `open /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`
8. Create a symlink called *sublime* by entering `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sublime`
9. Enter the following into your Mac Terminal: `open ~/.bash_profile` but if for whatever reason you don't have one configured, enter
   `sudo nano .bash_profile`.
10. Exit and open your bash profile; the following example should be contained in the profile `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`.  This is the same file location for other user-profile settings for applications like iTerm.
11. Test by entering the directory of app-files (e.g. `sublime .`).
12. Boom!  A special thanks to the great [Ashley Nolan's blog](https://ashleynolan.co.uk/blog/launching-sublime-from-the-terminal), though for
    whatever reason my new MacBookPro couldn't access the bash-profile, so I had to create one, which is why I included that caveat in step 4.  I trust
    this will assuage any systemAdmin anguish fellow developers may take for granted. :D